# Term independent of x and y in this expansion

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Find the term independent of $x$ and $y$ in
$$\left(x+y+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{xy}+2\right)^{20}$$

My attempt

factorised it as$$\frac{(x+y+2)(xy+1)-1)}{xy}$$ but still the method is too lengthy

Comment: Did you understand the question?  It should be obvious that the only term that does not involve x or y is $2^{20}= 1048576$.

Comment: there are more terms than that

Comment: @MathMan, there are more terms in the expansion, but that's the only one that doesn't have either $x$ or $y$.

Comment: @user247327: that is not true. For instance, the constant term in $\left(x+\frac{1}{x}+1\right)^2$ is $3$ and not $1$.

Comment: Oops. Mathman is right.  I  did not notice that the "x" and "1/x" terms will multiply to give terms to that do not involve x and the "y" and "1/y" terms will multiply to give terms that do not involve y.  There will be many more terms than the one I gave.

Comment: Yes, I also just saw it now.  Man I hate combinatorics and everything related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about the brutal way?
$$ \left(x+y+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{xy}+2\right)^{20} = \sum\binom{20}{a,b,c,d,e,f}2^f x^{a-c-e}y^{b-d-e} $$
where the sum is performed over the tuples $(a,b,c,d,e,f)\in\mathbb{N}^6$ such that $a+b+c+d+e+f=20$. If we are just interested in the constant term, we are just interested in the tuples for which $a=c+e$ and $b=d+e$, i.e. the triples $(c,d,e)\in\mathbb{N}^3$ such that $2c+2d+3e\leq 20$. The constant term is so given by
$$ \sum_{\substack{(c,d,e)\in\mathbb{N}^3\\2c+2d+3e\leq 20}}\frac{20!}{(c+e)!(d+e)!c!d!e!f!}2^f\quad \text{where}\;f=20-2c-2d-3d$$
that is trivially greater than $2^{20}+760\cdot 2^{18}$ (by restricting the sum just to $f=20$ and $f=18$, since $f=19$ is impossible). There are exactly $192$ triples contributing to the last sum. Thanks to Mathematica, the constant term is actually $\color{red}{737880155312536}$, between $2^{49}$ and $2^{50}$ and with a huge prime factor ($5957949707$).

Comment: the answer is either 2^60 or 40C20

Comment: @MathMan: try the command $$\text{SeriesCoefficient[(x + y + 1/x + 1/y + 1/(x y) + 2)^20, {x, 0, 0}, {y,
   0, 0}]}$$ in Mathematica and you will see that the answer is less than $2^{60}$ but has a huge prime factor ($5957949707$), so it is neither $\binom{40}{20}$.

Comment: Brutal is good! Bravo! (+1)

Comment: what is{ x,0,0} {y,0,0}?@JackD'Aurizio

Comment: @MathMan: that means we want to evaluate the Taylor series at $(x,y)=(0,0)$ and isolate the coefficient of $x^0 y^0$, i.e.the constant term.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio so the first 0 is for the value of x and the second is for the power of x?

Comment: @MathMan: exactly.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio then why if we change the value of x as 1 and y as 1 we get a diff answer?anyways its a constant term?

Comment: But it is the constant term of the Taylor expansion at another point. The constant term for $\sin(x)$ at $0$ is $0$, at $1$ is $\sin(1)$.

Comment: but woudnt the constant term in the function actually contain no x and y so shouldnt the constant term be independent of x and y?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47640/discussion-between-jack-daurizio-and-mathman).