# How to find the sum of this expression?

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I want to find the sum of the following expression in terms of $n$. I tried looking for it but couldn't come up with one. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

$$\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{4^i}\binom{2i}{i}$$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried to expand the (2i i) expression, but that didn't help.

Comment: [Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+binomial(2*i,i)%2F4%5Ei+for+i+from+0+to+n)

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series

Comment: [It's already answered here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1989966/summation-of-central-binomial-coefficients-divided-by-even-powers-of-2/1990702#1990702)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the extended binomial theorem we have
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^n}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}} $$
hence $\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{1}{4^i}\binom{2i}{i}$ can be seen as the coefficient of $x^n$ in $\frac{1}{(1-x)\sqrt{1-x}}$, since
$$ f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n x^n\quad \Longrightarrow\quad \frac{f(x)}{1-x}=\sum_{n\geq 0}A_n x^n,\quad A_n=a_0+a_1+\ldots+a_n.$$
On the other hand $\frac{1}{(1-x)\sqrt{1-x}}$ is just twice the derivative of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}$, hence
$$ \frac{1}{(1-x)\sqrt{1-x}} = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{2n x^{n-1}}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}$$
and by reindexing we get:
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{1}{4^i}\binom{2i}{i} = \frac{2(n+1)}{4^{n+1}}\binom{2n+2}{n+1}=\color{red}{\frac{2n+1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}}.$$

Comment: That was really helpful. Thanks a lot.