# Showing $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2k}{k} \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^k=\frac{2n+1}{4^n} \binom{2n}{n} $

Tags: combinatorics, summation, taylor-expansion, binomial-coefficients

I want to show that :
\begin{equation} \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2k}{k} \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^k=\frac{2n+1}{4^n} \binom{2n}{n} \end{equation}
I have no idea how to. I know it's the series for $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}$ at $1$ which diverges, but that doesn't give much information on the closed form of the sum. If there's a trick to solve this, I would be eager to know it.

Comment: Induction on $n$ is the first thing that comes to mind. What did you try? The question now has no context and should be closed.

Comment: @Ansper: There are powerful techniques to show such identities based upon *[Generating functions](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfology2.pdf)*. If you add some content on your post preventing it from being closed someone will presumably add an answer of this kind.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Summation of Central Binomial Coefficients divided by even powers of $2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1989966/summation-of-central-binomial-coefficients-divided-by-even-powers-of-2)

Answer (score 1):

I think we can show this by induction. The base case $n=0$ is clear. For the induction step, we have that
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \binom{2k}{k}\left( \frac{1}{k}\right)^k = \frac{2n+1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n} + \frac{1}{4^{n+1}} \binom{2(n+1)}{n+1}. $$
To evaluate this sum, recall that $\binom{n}{k}k=\binom{n-1}{k-1}n$ holds for all $n, k$, and so we have
$$ \begin{align*} 
\frac{2n+1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n} &= \frac{n+1}{4^n} \binom{2n+1}{n+1} \\
&= \frac{n+1}{4^n} \binom{2n+1}{n} \\
&= \frac{2n+2}{2 \cdot 4^n} \binom{2n+1}{n} \\
&= \frac{n+1}{2 \cdot 4^n} \binom{2n+2}{n+1}.
\end{align*}$$
This way, we get that
$$ \frac{2n+1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n} + \frac{1}{4^{n+1}} \binom{2(n+1)}{n+1} = \left( \frac{n+1}{2 \cdot 4^n} + \frac{1}{4^{n+1}} \right) \binom{2(n+1)}{n+1} = \frac{2(n+1)+2}{4^{n+1}} \binom{2(n+1)}{n+1}, $$
which shows the inductive step.